# Increase over the previous year with data from a dataset

Tags: python

a few days ago I took an exam at the university and in one of the exercises I was asked to find the increase compared to the previous year. The dataset had data from 2019 to 2022 and the increase was shown as the current year minus the previous year.
The difficulty in this code was that in order to relate the increase for 2019, 2018 must be considered as 0 since there is no data for this year.
An example:

```
2019 = valueof(2019)-valueof(2018)
2020 = valueof(2020)-valueof(2019)
2021 = valueof(2021)-valueof(2020)
2022 = valueof(2022)-valueof(2021)
```

My solution was:

```
def trainings_dict(trainings):
    dictionary = dict()
    for j in trainings:
        if j.timeandhour.year not in dictionary:
            dictionary[j.timeandhour.year] = [j.distance]
        else:
            dictionary[j.timeandhour.year].append(j.distance)
        
    return dictionary

def float_calc(a,b):
    try:
        return a-b
    except:
        return a

def year_increment_by_distance(trainings):
    distance_by_year = trainings_dict(trainings)
    sum_dict = defaultdict(float)
    for j in distance_by_year.items():
        if j[0] not in sum_dict:
            sum_dict[j[0]] = sum(j[1])
        else:
            sum_dict[j[0]] = sum(j[1])

    increment_dict = dict()

    for k in sum_dict.items():
        
        if k[0] not in increment_dict:
            increment_dict[k[0]] = float_calc(k[1],sum_dict.get(k[0]-1))
    
    return increment_dict
```

The training_dict function returns a dictionary that relates the year to the number of distances traveled, such as:

```
{
2019: [213,345,21,...],
2020: [192,541,346,...],
...
}
```

This function had already been used in another exercise, so reusing it would mean less code.

The float_calc function makes use of try and catch because when passing it the value of 2018 it would use catch and return the value of 2019, i.e. it would do the same as 2019-0.

I would like to know if my code is totally incorrect since, according to the professor who evaluated my exercise, I quote the correction "Spaghetti code". I think that the code is not a spaghetti code but an ingenious solution to a problem.
I would like to know your opinion before claiming another correction on the exercise.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: `pandas` package would make this much simpler. Are you allowed used pandas? What sort of solution was the professor looking for? Also, I don't understand the `timeandhour` code under `trainings_dict`; you never explained that requirement; is `timeandhour` your attribute, theirs, or some otehr package's?

Comment: One small thing that "pops" - in the function `year_increment_by_distance` you have exactly the same line of code for an `if` and for its `else`. Why is there even a condition?

Comment: Hi @smci, I cannot use pandas. The dataset is stored as a list of namedtuples, and the value of timeandhour corresponds to the type time. The teacher is looking for the increment with respect to the previous year, for example for 2019 we are looking to subtract the distance from 2018 to 2019 (2019-2018). Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Hi @Tomerikoo, reviewing the code I noticed that the if else would not have any added value, but I think it would not be enough to cross out the spaghetti code. Thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to point out:

- `float_calc` does not make sense of existing, if it is just a subtraction with error handling: you can try-catch on the caller side (`year_increment_by_distance`)
- In `trainings_dict` you can also use a `defaultdict` with lists to simplify your code. Even better, a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension) if possible.
- Same thing for `year_increment_by_distance`: use a dictionary comprehension, or anyway avoid `for k in sum_dict.items():` in favor of the more explicit `for k, v in sum_dict.items():` so that you won't have to `k[0]`